# Milstein discretization of the CIR process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, differential-equations

Given the CIR process $\ dX_t = (a − bX_t ) dt + 
\sigma \sqrt{X_t}dW_t$ - I want to show that its Milstein scheme is  $\ X_{i+1} - X_i = ((a − bX_i) - 0.25\sigma^2)\Delta + \sigma\sqrt{X_i}\sqrt{\Delta\epsilon_i}+ 0.25\sigma^2\Delta\epsilon^2  d$ - so that the innovation term can be written as $\ X_{i+1} = A_i(\epsilon_{i+1} + \sqrt{C_i}^2) + B_i = A_iZ_{i+1} + B_i$,  where A_i, B_i, C_i are functions of of X_i and I want to give A_i, B_i, C_i for the CIR.

Comment: What is your question, do you want help deriving the step? What did you try?

Comment: yes exactly I need help to rewrite the innovation term with the parameters A_i, B_i and C_i as functions of X_i. I was able to derive the solution of the process, but don't really know where to start with the rewriting process.